# NullPointerException no android em projeto para download de PDFs

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Eu fiz uma aplicação que em um determinado momento baixo PDFs, porém só consigo baixar um PDF. Queria baixar vários PDF, vejam o projeto. A parte que está dando o erro é no `for`, onde tento chamar 3 vezes a parte que lê o PDF. Se eu jogar apenas 1 string sem o `for` funciona. Vejam:

Classe de **Download**

```java
public class AndroidFileDownloader extends Activity  {
    // Used to communicate state changes in the DownloaderThread
    public static final int MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_STARTED = 1000;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE = 1001;
    public static final int MESSAGE_UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR = 1002;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_CANCELED = 1003;
    public static final int MESSAGE_CONNECTING_STARTED = 1004;
    public static final int MESSAGE_ENCOUNTERED_ERROR = 1005;

    // instance variables
    private AndroidFileDownloader thisActivity;
    private Thread downloaderThread;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        thisActivity = this;
        downloaderThread = null;
        progressDialog = null;


        //Cria o arquivo

        File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");

        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();

        File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, "/Wallpaper/");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String links[] = null;

        links[0] = "http://lwn.net/images/pdf/20040806_novell_mtd.pdf";
        links[1] = "http://lwn.net/images/pdf/IBM-155.pdf";
        links[2] = "http://lwn.net/images/pdf/IBM-148.pdf";

        for(int i =0; i <=links.length; i++){

        downloaderThread = new DownloaderThread(thisActivity, links[i]);

        downloaderThread.start();
        }

    }

    /**
     * This is the Handler for this activity. It will receive messages from the
     * DownloaderThread and make the necessary updates to the UI.
     */
    public Handler activityHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            /*
             * Handling MESSAGE_UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR: 1. Get the current
             * progress, as indicated in the arg1 field of the Message. 2.
             * Update the progress bar.
             */
            case MESSAGE_UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR:
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    int currentProgress = msg.arg1;
                    progressDialog.setProgress(currentProgress);
                }
                break;

            /*
             * Handling MESSAGE_CONNECTING_STARTED: 1. Get the URL of the file
             * being downloaded. This is stored in the obj field of the Message.
             * 2. Create an indeterminate progress bar. 3. Set the message that
             * should be sent if user cancels. 4. Show the progress bar.
             */
            case MESSAGE_CONNECTING_STARTED:
                if (msg.obj != null && msg.obj instanceof String) {
                    String url = (String) msg.obj;
                    // truncate the url
                    if (url.length() > 16) {
                        String tUrl = url.substring(0, 15);
                        tUrl += "...";
                        url = tUrl;
                    }
                    String pdTitle = thisActivity
                            .getString(R.string.progress_dialog_title_connecting);
                    String pdMsg = thisActivity
                            .getString(R.string.progress_dialog_message_prefix_connecting);
                    pdMsg += " " + url;

                    dismissCurrentProgressDialog();
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(thisActivity);
                    progressDialog.setTitle(pdTitle);
                    progressDialog.setMessage(pdMsg);
                    progressDialog
                            .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                    // set the message to be sent when this dialog is canceled
                    Message newMsg = Message.obtain(this,
                            MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_CANCELED);
                    progressDialog.setCancelMessage(newMsg);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
                break;

            /*
             * Crie uma barra de progresso com
             * Especificado valor máximo e atual valor 0; atribuí-la a
             * ProgressDialog . O campo arg1 conterá o valor max . 2. Defina
             * O título e um texto para a barra de progresso . O campo do obj
             * Mensagem conterá uma String que representa o nome do
             * Arquivo a ser baixado . 3. Defina a mensagem que deve ser enviada se
             * Diálogo é cancelada. 4. Verifique a barra de progresso visível.
             */
            case MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_STARTED:
                // obj will contain a String representing the file name
                if (msg.obj != null && msg.obj instanceof String) {
                    int maxValue = msg.arg1;
                    String fileName = (String) msg.obj;
                    String pdTitle = thisActivity
                            .getString(R.string.progress_dialog_title_downloading);
                    String pdMsg = thisActivity
                            .getString(R.string.progress_dialog_message_prefix_downloading);
                    pdMsg += " " + fileName;

                    dismissCurrentProgressDialog();
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(thisActivity);
                    progressDialog.setTitle(pdTitle);
                    progressDialog.setMessage(pdMsg);
                    progressDialog
                            .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                    progressDialog.setMax(maxValue);
                    // set the message to be sent when this dialog is canceled
                    Message newMsg = Message.obtain(this,
                            MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_CANCELED);
                    progressDialog.setCancelMessage(newMsg);
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
                break;

            /*
             * Handling MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE: 1. Remove the progress bar
             * from the screen. 2. Display Toast that says download is complete.
             */
            case MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE:
                dismissCurrentProgressDialog();
                displayMessage(getString(R.string.user_message_download_complete));
                break;

            /*
             * Handling MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_CANCELLED: 1. Interrupt the downloader
             * thread. 2. Remove the progress bar from the screen. 3. Display
             * Toast that says download is complete.
             */
            case MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_CANCELED:
                if (downloaderThread != null) {
                    downloaderThread.interrupt();
                }
                dismissCurrentProgressDialog();
                displayMessage(getString(R.string.user_message_download_canceled));
                break;

            /*
             * Handling MESSAGE_ENCOUNTERED_ERROR: 1. Check the obj field of the
             * message for the actual error message that will be displayed to
             * the user. 2. Remove any progress bars from the screen. 3. Display
             * a Toast with the error message.
             */
            case MESSAGE_ENCOUNTERED_ERROR:
                // obj will contain a string representing the error message
                if (msg.obj != null && msg.obj instanceof String) {
                    String errorMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                    dismissCurrentProgressDialog();
                    displayMessage(errorMessage);
                }
                break;

            default:
                // nothing to do here
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * If there is a progress dialog, dismiss it and set progressDialog to null.
     */
    public void dismissCurrentProgressDialog() {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.hide();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Displays a message to the user, in the form of a Toast.
     * 
     * @param message
     *            Message to be displayed.
     */
    public void displayMessage(String message) {
        if (message != null) {
            Toast.makeText(thisActivity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void openFolder() {

              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
              intent.setType("Wallpaper/*");
              startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Classe de **Thread**

```java
public class DownloaderThread extends Thread {
    // constants
    private static final int DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    // instance variables
    private AndroidFileDownloader parentActivity;
    private String downloadUrl;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new DownloaderThread object.
     * 
     * @param parentActivity
     *            Reference to AndroidFileDownloader activity.
     * @param inUrl
     *            String representing the URL of the file to be downloaded.
     */
    public DownloaderThread(AndroidFileDownloader inParentActivity, String inUrl) {
        downloadUrl = "";
        if (inUrl != null) {
            downloadUrl = inUrl;
        }
        parentActivity = inParentActivity;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the URL of the file, begins the download, and notifies the
     * AndroidFileDownloader activity of changes in state. Writes the file to
     * the root of the SD card.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        URL url;
        URLConnection conn;
        int fileSize, lastSlash;
        String fileName;
        BufferedInputStream inStream;
        BufferedOutputStream outStream;
        File outFile;
        FileOutputStream fileStream;
        Message msg;

        // we're going to connect now
        msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
                AndroidFileDownloader.MESSAGE_CONNECTING_STARTED, 0, 0,
                downloadUrl);
        parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        try {
            url = new URL(downloadUrl);
            conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            fileSize = conn.getContentLength();

            // get the filename
            lastSlash = url.toString().lastIndexOf('/');
            fileName = "file.bin";
            if (lastSlash >= 0) {
                fileName = url.toString().substring(lastSlash + 1);
            }
            if (fileName.equals("")) {
                fileName = "file.bin";
            }

            // notify download start
            int fileSizeInKB = fileSize / 1024;
            msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
                    AndroidFileDownloader.MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_STARTED,
                    fileSizeInKB, 0, fileName);
            parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            // start download
            inStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Wallpaper/"
                    + fileName);
            fileStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileStream,
                    DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE);
            byte[] data = new byte[DOWNLOAD_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = 0, totalRead = 0;
            while (!isInterrupted()
                    && (bytesRead = inStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) >= 0) {
                outStream.write(data, 0, bytesRead);

                // update progress bar
                totalRead += bytesRead;
                int totalReadInKB = totalRead / 1024;
                msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
                        AndroidFileDownloader.MESSAGE_UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR,
                        totalReadInKB, 0);
                parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }

            outStream.close();
            fileStream.close();
            inStream.close();

            if (isInterrupted()) {
                // the download was canceled, so let's delete the partially
                // downloaded file
                outFile.delete();
            } else {
                // notify completion
                msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
                        AndroidFileDownloader.MESSAGE_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
                parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            String errMsg = parentActivity
                    .getString(R.string.error_message_bad_url);
            msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
                    AndroidFileDownloader.MESSAGE_ENCOUNTERED_ERROR, 0, 0,
                    errMsg);
            parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            String errMsg = parentActivity
                    .getString(R.string.error_message_file_not_found);
            msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
                    AndroidFileDownloader.MESSAGE_ENCOUNTERED_ERROR, 0, 0,
                    errMsg);
            parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String errMsg = parentActivity
                    .getString(R.string.error_message_general);
            msg = Message.obtain(parentActivity.activityHandler,
                    AndroidFileDownloader.MESSAGE_ENCOUNTERED_ERROR, 0, 0,
                    errMsg);
            parentActivity.activityHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }

}
```

Analisem o código e vejam como posso baixar vários PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Se você teve um `NullPointerException`, você podia postar o stacktrace, né?
2. No método `run()` da sua classe `DownloaderThread`, você não está fechando o `outStream`, o `inStream` e o `fileStream` dentro de um bloco `finally`. Isso daí provavelmente vai lhe causar problemas.
3. Posso estar errado, mas eu acho que atualizar o estado da barra de progresso constantemente no seu `while` que faz o download provavelmente vai causar algum tipo de problema de desempenho que vai diminuir a velocidade do download.
4. O campo `thisActivity` me parece ser totalmente desnecesssário. Use `AndroidFileDownloader.this`.
5. Este código **definitivamente** está errado:

```java
    for(int i =0; i <=links.length; i++){

    downloaderThread = new DownloaderThread(thisActivity, links[i]);

    downloaderThread.start();
    }
```

Você cria 3 threads de forma quase instantânea. O campo `downloaderThread` conterá uma referência apenas à última destas threads no final. Isso significa que as três estarão acessando o `parentActivity.activityHandler` simultaneamente, deixando-o confuso. Além disso, o `activityHandler` usa o campo `downloaderThread` que vai se referir a última thread, mesmo se o código for ativado pelas outras threads, resultando em uma thread interferir na outra. Talvez (ou talvez não) você tenha que criar um `Handler` e uma `ProgressDialog` por thread e passar o `Handler` como parâmetro no construtor da `DownloaderThread` ao invés do `thisActivity`.

6. Os limites do seu `for` estão errados:

```java
for(int i =0; i <=links.length; i++){
```

Por causa daquele `<=`, os índices serão de 0 até 3, e não de 0 até 2. Ao tentar acessar `links[i]` aonde `i = 3`, você vai ter um `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

7. E aqui está o seu `NullPointerException`:

```java
    String links[] = null;

    links[0] = "http://lwn.net/images/pdf/20040806_novell_mtd.pdf";
    links[1] = "http://lwn.net/images/pdf/IBM-155.pdf";
    links[2] = "http://lwn.net/images/pdf/IBM-148.pdf";
```

Se `links` é `null`, `links[0]` é `NullPointerException`! O que você queria é isso:

```java
    String[] links = {
        "http://lwn.net/images/pdf/20040806_novell_mtd.pdf",
        "http://lwn.net/images/pdf/IBM-155.pdf",
        "http://lwn.net/images/pdf/IBM-148.pdf"
    };
```

Comment: nesse caso, como declaro a variavel global, e preencho os links em outro lugar?

Comment: @WarLock Você pode usar uma `ArrayList`.